# Unable to deploy Django app on Bluemix with new cflinuxfs2 stack

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to deploy my Django app on Bluemix but I am getting following error:

[image: Log]

What will be the solution for this?

Comment: Please avoid pasting text/code/errors as images.

Comment: ^ Agree with the above - if you can swap out the image for a pasted error in text format, that is more readable. Please also refrain from marking questions as urgent - all questions are of equal importance here.

Comment: please share your push command and/or your manifest.yml. I'm able to use the cflinuxfs2 stack

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem on the system at the time and was not the fault of your application. You should be able to push your code now without that error.